# PHP: Sort numeric array by distance to given value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

*Problem:*

I need to sort an numeric array by its distance to an given value. Meaning the numbers closest to the given value, should come first. Performance is not a must, but still appreciated.

*Example:*

Given I have an array `$array = array(1000, 1050, 1100, 1125);`.

`mySortFunction($array, 1090);` should result in `array(1100, 1125, 1050, 1000)`

Comment: You brought your homework here. Never bring your homework here. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use PHPs built-in `usort()` function.

Comment: `function mySortFunction(&$array, $value) {
    usort(
        $array,
        function ($a, $b) use ($value) {
            return abs($a - $value) > abs($b - $value);
        }
    );
}
`

Comment: @deceze It's not a duplicate but just a redirection to your question!

Comment: @Shawnley Here's an answer as a comment since it was wrongly flaged as duplicate:

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}


function sortArrByDistance(&$arr, $i)
{
 if (!empty($arr)) {
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
   $tmpArr[$value] = abs($i - $value);
  uasort($tmpArr, 'cmp');
  foreach ($tmpArr as $key => $value)
   $newArr[] = $key;
  return $newArr;
 } else
  return null;
}

var_dump(sortArrByDistance($array, 2000));

Comment: @Adam It's a redirect to the general reference for how to sort arrays. The OP should attempt a solution using that, it usually covers 99% of the problems people have with sorting arrays. Coming up with an appropriate comparison function based on the information given there should be pretty simple. If the OP still needs help with the specifics of such a comparison function, he should make that clear in the question.

Comment: Mark Baker & Adam Sinclair - Thank you for your help! Though I don't know how to remove the "duplicate" status, so that you can answer.